# CSS: 3 row (header,footer,content) liquid layout, trying to make middle one expand on window.resize

Tags: css, resize, fluid-layout

I'm building a 3 row liquid layout. I have a fixed height header and a footer. I also have a minimum width for the wrapper (for these 3 rows).

The problem is, I can't make the middle one (`#content`) resize vertically. If I make **position:absolute** then I lose control over scrolling. I thought I could do it using the `top`,`bottom`,`margin` and `padding` while setting the `height` to 100% but I couldn't.

Here's the code that I'm using to test it and here's the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/inhan/kUZgY/ You will see that the lighter gray background won't expand when window is resized.

I'm willing to use CSS only and not use HTML5 features. What am I missing? Thanks for any input.

### CSS

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    height:100%; 
    max-height:100%; 
}
* html body { /*IE6 hack*/
    padding:30px 0;
}
* html #content { /*IE6 hack*/
    height:100%; 
    width:100%; 
}
#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    min-width:800px;
    min-height:100%;
    position:absolute;
}

#header, #footer {
    position:absolute; 
    left:0; 
    width:100%; 
    height:30px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:gray;
    color:white;
}
#header {
    top:0;
}
#footer {
    bottom:0;
}

#content {
    margin:31px 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}​
```

### HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">This is header</div>
        <div id="footer">This is footer</div>
        <div id="content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi commodo, ipsum sed pharetra gravida, orci magna rhoncus neque, id pulvinar odio lorem non turpis. Nullam sit amet enim. Suspendisse id velit vitae ligula volutpat condimentum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra posuere sapien. Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget euismod ullamcorper, lectus nunc ullamcorper orci, fermentum bibendum enim nibh eget ipsum. Donec porttitor ligula eu dolor. Maecenas vitae nulla consequat libero cursus venenatis. Nam magna enim, accumsan eu, blandit sed, blandit a, eros.<br/><br/>Quisque facilisis erat a dui. Nam malesuada ornare dolor. Cras gravida, diam sit amet rhoncus ornare, erat elit consectetuer erat, id egestas pede nibh eget odio. Proin tincidunt, velit vel porta elementum, magna diam molestie sapien, non aliquet massa pede eu diam. Aliquam iaculis. Fusce et ipsum et nulla tristique facilisis. Donec eget sem sit amet ligula viverra gravida. Etiam vehicula urna vel turpis. Suspendisse sagittis ante a urna. Morbi a est quis orci consequat rutrum. Nullam egestas feugiat felis. Integer adipiscing semper ligula. Nunc molestie, nisl sit amet cursus convallis, sapien lectus pretium metus, vitae pretium enim wisi id lectus. Donec vestibulum. Etiam vel nibh. Nulla facilisi. Mauris pharetra. Donec augue. Fusce ultrices, neque id dignissim ultrices, tellus mauris dictum elit, vel lacinia enim metus eu nunc.
        </div>
    </div>​
</body>
```

### Extra Info

I'm actually not really interested in setting a minimum width for the whole page but some middle content will need that. So if I can, I might wanna make the whole structure respect when there's **min-width** property in the content that is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

This should be what you're after http://jsfiddle.net/kUZgY/6/

You were just missing `html {height:100%;}`

I also changed the `#header` and `#footer` to `position:fixed`

Comment: Thank you. Well I was okay with header and footer to scroll with the content because I actually have an absolute-positioned logo that extends the header in the real scenario, which should not lose relation with the content. Also, there's this extra header/footer's space to scroll now.